# mod_rewrite redirection of specifically named files causing a loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a little trouble with the following rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^dir_([a-z\\-]*).php$ /dir/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dir/([a-z\\-]*)(/)?$ /dir_$1.php [L]
```

I want to redirect all files that follow the style **dir_file-name.php** to **dir/file-name/** and show the content from the php file.

The first rule alone works fine and redirects, but it doesn't show content. So I made the second rule and it just created a loop preventing the page from loading at all. How do I solve this? Sorry my skills in regex and apache aren't the best.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use a RewriteCond to check what the _originally_ requested URI was. Only if that was `dir_file-name.php`, you want to do the external redirect.

Comment: Or the `END` flag for the second rule could also help, if you’re on Apache 2.4+

Comment: Thanks, i never knew about the `END` tag. that worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RewriteCond to check what the *originally* requested URI was. Only if that was `dir_file-name.php`, you want to do the external redirect.

Or the `END` flag for the second rule could also help, if you’re on Apache 2.4+
( It prevents the “looping” that happens when rewriting is configured in .htaccess context, where the rewritten internal URL is fed into the whole process again, unless no rules applied any more.)